# How can I make a duplicated object (Alt + D) a single object again?

Tags: objects

I copied the properties from one object to multiple objects and then duplicated these objects with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, now I want to convert them to single objects to modify specific ones.

Comment: You could have just used `Shift + D`. This will duplicate objects and create unique copies.

Comment: select the object and hit U >> Object & Data